# iOS How to cancel a scheduled localnotification

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification

I am writing an iPhone app in which I have three countdown timers, that each set a local notification when they are started by the user (IBAction).

My question is, how can I reference to an existing local notification elsewhere in the code? I have tried referencing it directly like this which crashes:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:myNotification];
```

And like this after scheduling the notification and adding it to the user defaults:

```
In my scheduling method...
[myDefaults setObject:myNotification forKey:@"myNotification"];
...

And in my cancelling method...
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:[myDefaults objectForKey:@"myNotification"]];
[myDefaults synchronize];
```

My app crashes with a SIGABRT error on the cancelLocalNotification line above. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a working solution to my issue after thinking it through step by step. I found I was going about the whole issue entirely the wrong way!

Essentially, I found you don't need any local notifications when the app is active (i.e. in foreground). So instead of setting the local notification when the timer is started, I set the relevant notifications up when the app is about to resign.

I put these observers in my viewDidLoad;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(appWillResign) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(appIsActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
object:nil];
```

and in my appWillResign method, I set up the notifications for any active timers. When the app is resumed, I simply cancel ALL the notifications.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

In short, you shouldn't need to reference the notifications elsewhere in the code. You only set them up when they are absolutely needed: when the app is backgrounded! So you really don't need to 'store' them anywhere for later use.

Thanks for your contribution @Learner, you helped put me on the right track! :D

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to predict but generally SIGABRT comes when you access an nil or released object.

So in  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:myNotification];` `

it can be "myNotification" which is nil.

OR if `[myDefaults objectForKey:@"myNotification"] returns nil`.

Possible resason for that can be that `NsUserDefaults` stores only few data type as mentioned in following paragraph of class reference.

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

What i can predict is that `myNotification` which is being stored is of type `UILocalNotification.` so probably storing of data is failing.

Please debug the code further and post if above cases are not working.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to sync the `NSUserDefaults`. I'm assuming you just set the object and did not synchronize it. If so the object will not actually save to `NSUserDefaults`, rather just to the local `NSUserDefaults` object. What you need to do is call `[defaults synchronize]` after setting the object.